# Passing String Intent in onStop of Fragment

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments

I had a 2 hour excursion with a problem in which I could not pass a simple string via Intent back to the calling FragmentActivity.

My code to start the FragmentActivity that was to return data via Intent was simple:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_NEWCATCH);
```

The code in the target FragmentActivity attempted to pass back a String as follows:

```
String mImagePath; // this is the string I want to pass

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH, mImagePath);
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
```

I got null everytime when I read the value in my onActivityResult like this:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_NEWCATCH) {
    String imgfile_path = data.getStringExtra(NewCatchFragment.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH);
Log.d(TAG, "imgfile_path=" + imgfile_path);
}
```

I tried passing an integer no problem. I changed it to pass a string constant such as "fubar" like this no problem:

```
i.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_FILENAME, "fubar");
```

That's when I realized something else was amiss. It turns out the problem seemed to be because I was performing the setResult operation in the onStop() method of the FragmentActivity. As soon as I moved the code that set the intent into another "earlier" method it worked fine.

I have no idea why this should be a problem. I am certainly able to print and access the variable, and the system seems capable of passing both an integer or string constant through the intent in onStop, but not a variable that belonged to the derived FragmentActivity class itself that was running (declared String mImagePath just beneath the class declaration).

I found nothing via searches on why this should be an issue. When the FragmentActivity hits onStop (and I am using the support library) it should still have everything it needs in place to complete this. Can someone more informed please explain what I am not seeing here?

Edit One other thing - my fragments are "retained" - is it possible some activity-related storage needed is not available at the time the fragment onStop is called?